# What should I use instead of clutter_score_new?

Tags: c, clutter

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/clutter-beginners-tutorial#null) on Clutter, and as you can imagine, it's pretty out of date, with my GCC throwing all manner of deprecation warnings about. As I don't want them to be chucked around (things get deprecated for a reason), I managed to get around most things in there by either following the warnings' advice, or by judiciously researching the Clutter reference.

However, one of the sections (the one about scores) requires me to use `clutter_score_new`. According to both the GCC warnings and the [reference material](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterScore.html#clutter-score-new), this is deprecated, with no alternatives or suggestions given. Having looked at the documentation, I'm a bit lost - what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClutterScore` was a bad class that, sadly, was not removed in time before 1.0 got released.

you can achieve the same effect using `ClutterTimeline` and markers to connect/start/stop timelines in a hierarchical way.

to be fair, though, there's no real reason to use `ClutterTimeline` directly these days. you can use the [implicit animation API directly](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/migrating-ClutterAnimation.html#id-1.9.6.12), or the [explicit Transition API](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterKeyframeTransition.html).

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I need a more up-to-date tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Many API have been deprecated since. I updated the code with ClutterPropertyTransition. For instance to animate rect1 rectangle you could use:

```
ClutterTransition *transition = clutter_property_transition_new("rotation-angle-z");
clutter_timeline_set_progress_mode(CLUTTER_TIMELINE(transition), CLUTTER_LINEAR);
clutter_timeline_set_duration(CLUTTER_TIMELINE(transition), msecs);
clutter_timeline_set_repeat_count(CLUTTER_TIMELINE(transition), -1);
clutter_transition_set_animatable(transition, CLUTTER_ANIMATABLE(rect1));
clutter_transition_set_from(transition, G_TYPE_FLOAT, 0.0);
clutter_transition_set_to(transition, G_TYPE_FLOAT, 360.0);
clutter_timeline_start(CLUTTER_TIMELINE(transition));
```

Do not forget to release the reference to "transition" when done